# \includegraphicx dynamic filename from \usekomavar

Tags: graphics, koma-script, scrlttr2

I am writing a letter with scrlttr2, which makes use of the KOMA script package.

In an .lco file I have the following (which gives me a headache):

```
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[height=\useplength{signatureimageheight}]{\usekomavar{signatureimage}}\\
\usekomavar{fromname}}
```

The error I get is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\filename@simple ...#2\\}\fi \edef \filename@base
                                                  {#1}
l.11 \closing{kthxbye,}
```

If I replace the `\usekomavar{signatureimage}` with `my-signature.pdf` everything is fine, but how can I make things dynamic?

`\usekomavar{signatureimage}` produces `my-signature.pdf`

**MWE** (actually: minimal error-producing example):

letter.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Recipient\\
Address}
\LoadLetterOption{my-details}
\setkomavar{subject}{subject}
\opening{Hi,}
Lorem ipsum.
\closing{kthxbye,} 
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

my-details.lco:

```
\ProvidesFile{my-details.lco}[2013/08/16 lco (My Details)]
\LoadLetterOption{letter-p1}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Me Myself}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{My Address}
\setkomavar{signatureimage}{my-signature.pdf}

\LoadLetterOption{letter-p2}
```

letter-p1.lco:

```
\ProvidesFile{letter-p2.lco}[2013/08/16 lco (letter-p2)]
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,foldmarks=true,foldmarks=mvp,subject=titled}
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}

\newkomavar{signatureimage}
\setkomavar*{signatureimage}{filename of signaure image (including extension)}

\@newplength{signatureimageheight}
\@setplength{signatureimageheight}{\useplength{sigbeforevskip}}
```

letter-p2.lco **(This is where the dynamic file screws things up)**:

```
\ProvidesFile{letter-p2.lco}[2013/08/16 lco (letter-p2)]

\ifkomavarempty{signatureimage}{%true-code
}
{%false-code
    \setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[height=\useplength{signatureimageheight}]{\usekomavar{signatureimage}}\\
\usekomavar{fromname}}
    \@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{0cm}
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I added one. I'ts rather complex for a MWE due to the many (3) external files.

Comment: I don't get any error.

Comment: The MWE posted above is a *working* example. The error can be produced by changing the `\includegraphics` line in letter-p2.lco to the one at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Please, make clearer what's the code producing the error.

Comment: I changed the MWE to a "minimal error-producing example": Using the updated listed code in the question will now let you reproduce the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\usekomavar` cannot be used directly as file name in `\includegraphics`:

- It is *not* expandable, it is defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand`.
- The file name parser needs to see the dot that separates the extension.

**Workaround:**

`\usekomavar` has an optional argument, that can be used to define a temporary macro that will expand to the file name. The expansion is done by `\edef`:

```
\usekomavar[\edef\tmp]{signatureimage}%
\includegraphics[%
    height=50mm,%
]{\tmp}%
```

The file name parser of LaTeX expands the first token of the file name, thus the file name extension will be seen, if `\tmp` is expanded once.

Comment: Same without need for `\tmp`: `\usekomavar[{\includegraphics[height=50mm]}]{signatureimage}`